# Is there any wat to fit the content into single page in Select PDF .Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, html-to-pdf, selectpdf

I have written a code in .Net Core that converts the html into pdf. The nuget manager tools I used for this conversion in SelectPdf.

```
                SelectPdf.HtmlToPdf pdf = new SelectPdf.HtmlToPdf();
                System.Drawing.SizeF size = new System.Drawing.SizeF(750, 750);
                pdf.Options.PdfPageCustomSize = size;
                pdf.Options.PdfPageSize = SelectPdf.PdfPageSize.A4;

                SelectPdf.PdfDocument pdfDoc = pdf.ConvertHtmlString(html);

                using var ms = new MemoryStream();
                pdfDoc.Save(ms);
                return ms.ToArray();
```

The code is working fine, currently, the size is in A4. The problem is when there is a huge amount of data in HTML the data is split into different pages example the below.

[image]

Is there any way so that all the content in the HTML remains on the same page in pdf?

Comment: Are you creating the HTML? Does the PDF convertor respond to [@media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) CSS queries? Do you want to shrink all the content onto one page, or make it add page breaks at sensible places?

Comment: You can read this using article for page setup: https://selectpdf.com/html-to-pdf/docs/html/ResizingContentDuringConversion.html

Comment: @Chaodeng the site is down

Comment: @BirajDahal The link had "html" on the end instead of "htm": [Resizing Content During Conversion with Select.Pdf Html to Pdf Converter](https://selectpdf.com/html-to-pdf/docs/html/ResizingContentDuringConversion.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You can try AutoFit options;

```
    var converter = new HtmlToPdf
    {
        Options =
        {
            // set converter options
            PdfPageSize = PdfPageSize.A4,
            PdfPageOrientation = PdfPageOrientation.Landscape,
            AutoFitHeight = HtmlToPdfPageFitMode.AutoFit,
            AutoFitWidth = HtmlToPdfPageFitMode.AutoFit,
            // set css @media print
            CssMediaType = HtmlToPdfCssMediaType.Print
        }
    };
```